# create orgmode buffer without name in specific directory

Tags: org-mode, buffers

I want to create a function that creates a new orgmode buffer where I could type and at the end save in a predefined directory. If this is not possible, then create the buffer with a name in a directory, and after editing, be able to rename it.

Comment: Honestly both things that you say are possible. 
Maybe will be a little more than what you want but `org-roam-find-file` function does same behavior for me. 
The way that it's work *>>*
1. > Find file > If buffer name is different than all create necessary org-buffer in predefined directory.
It brings also tons of additional feature. It's good to look and create your own flow.

Comment: Thanks. I tried org-roam-find-file but it prompts for a location. I would like my location to be already predifined in this function I try to create.

Comment: I understand you don't want any interactive action at all.

Comment: Well, interactive in the sense I can call it! :D

Comment: `(find-file "/path/to/directory/filename.org")` ? Then you can save without changing the file name or you can `C-x C-w` and fix the name.  Or `(let ((default-directory "/path/to/directory")) (switch-to-buffer "filename.org")` ? Not sure if that's what you are asking.